# Is it possible to extract data from a parts catalog software

Tags: database, encryption, extract, data-extraction

I need to extract all the data I can find from these parts catalogs. Each catalog is in its own folder that looks like this.

[image]

Here is the PEid from the application

[image]

Here is how that data looks like when its viewed in the software.

[image]

Here is a list of all the files in the application directory

```
ASYCFILT.DLL
BIN
BTRDP32.ocx
btrv.reg
catalog.dll
COMCAT.DLL
COMCT332.OCX
COMDLG32.OCX
DAO350.DLL
dao360.dll
DBADAPT.DLL
DBGRID32.OCX
DBLIST32.OCX
expsrv.dll
Findfile.avi
IMGADMIN.OCX
IMGCMN.DLL
IMGEDIT.OCX
IMGSCAN.OCX
IMGSHL.DLL
IMGTHUMB.OCX
jdX.exe
MFC42.DLL
msado21.tlb
MSADODC.OCX
MSBIND.DLL
MSCOMCT2.OCX
MSCOMCTL.OCX
MSCOMM32.OCX
MSDATGRD.OCX
MSDATLST.OCX
MSDERUN.DLL
MSFLXGRD.OCX
MSHFLXGD.OCX
MSJET35.DLL
msjet40.dll
MSJINT35.DLL
msjint40.dll
MSJTER35.DLL
msjter40.dll
msjtes40.dll
MSMAPI32.OCX
MSMASK32.OCX
MSRD2X35.DLL
msrd2x40.dll
msrd3x40.dll
MSREPL35.DLL
msrepl40.dll
MSSTDFMT.DLL
MSVBVM50.DLL
MSVBVM60.DLL
MSVCIRT.DLL
msvcrt.dll
MSVCRT40.DLL
mswdat10.dll
mswstr10.dll
OIADM400.DLL
OICOM400.DLL
OIDIS400.DLL
OIFIL400.DLL
OIGFS400.DLL
OIPRT400.DLL
OISLB400.DLL
OISSQ400.DLL
OITWA400.DLL
OIUI400.DLL
OLEAUT32.DLL
oleDB.dll
OLEPRO32.DLL
path.dat
prcopts.dat
print.txt
recall.dat
reg.bat
REGICON.OCX
RICHED32.DLL
RICHTX32.OCX
scrrun.dll
SIMPDATA.TLB
STDOLE2.TLB
SYSINFO.OCX
sysprint.dat
TABCTL32.OCX
Uninstall.exe
unreg.bat
VB5DB.DLL
VB6STKIT.DLL
VBAJET32.DLL
vsflex8l.ocx
W32mkde.exe
W32mkrc.dll
Wbtrv32.dll
WBTRVC32.DLL
```

Here is a listing one of the PARTLIST.DAT files from XORStrings

[image]

**How can i extract the data from the files?** 
I've been looking at reverse engineering but not sure which direction to go with that. Do I have to start at the application (exe) level to get the data extracted? Can I not find a way to extract directly from the dat file itself?

I used IDA to upend the dat file and I can see the data that matches the application. But I cannot extract that data without pulling all the raw data with it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing a question or problem here. So what's preventing you from accomplishing your task? Can you provide more detail? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the questions with much more detail